# PHP Error Log HTML Email Headers

Tags: php, html, email, error-handling

quicky question. 
I have set a custom error handler for an application I am making that writes to an error log and will also generate an html email to the main administrator using the code below.

```
function log_to_errors($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars){

if(ENVIRONMENT !== 'development'):
    ini_set('log_errors', 1);
    ini_set('error_log', '../error_logs.txt');

    $email = "
        <div style='background: rgb(224, 224, 224); padding: 5px 10px;'>
            <p>An error reference of ".$number." has occured on line: ".$line." in: <strong>".$file."</strong></p>
            <p>".$message."</p>
            <pre>".print_r($vars, 1)."</pre>
        </div>
    ";

    $email_header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;';
    error_log($email, 1, ADMIN_EMAIL, $email_header); 
endif;
}

set_error_handler('log_to_errors');
```

I would like to amend this line:

```
$email_header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;'
```

so that I can set custom information for the other email credentials ie the 'from and subject' elements of the email but when I try and do something like this:

```
$email_header = 'From:errors@example.com; Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;';
```

it breaks the html in the email.
Can someone point me in the right direction so I can set a message subject etc for the email.

Many thanks,
Lewis

Comment: Try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a `dot (.)` before `$email_header` ..

try this..

```
$email_header = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;'
$email_header .= 'From:errors@example.com; Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;';
```

you were not `concating` the `$email_header` string..

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, I'm not trying to concatenate here. I was just illustrating what it was that I was trying to do. I only have the following line: $email_header = 'From:errors@example.com; Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;';

Comment: ohh ok. no problem.. try putting `ob_clean()` or `ob_flush()` function before declaring your `$email` variable...

Comment: Sadly didnt work my friend. Thanks anyway for trying. Any other ideas?

Comment: may be this could help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738685/php-send-mail-with-html-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . chr(13) . chr(10);
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . chr(13) . chr(10);
    $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . chr(13) . chr(10);

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: '. $to . chr(13) . chr(10);
    $headers .= 'From: '. $from . chr(13) . chr(10); 
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '. $clientmail . chr(13) . chr(10) . chr(13) . chr(10);
```